# Stress Test Interpretation

Tags: high-load, load-testing, stress-testing

I ran a basic stress test and am having trouble interpreting the results.

Setup

- Super simple node.js API (returns a string for a GET request) deployed on heroku's free tier
- Increased RPS until I started to see a lag in average response time (unfortunately the tool I was using didn't allow a p90, etc, just average)
- Datadog integration for monitoring

While I did hit a threshold (2.5k rps) I started to see a slowdown, I didn't see anything in DataDog to indicate stress - RAM, CPU.

If it's not CPU or RAM, what is likely causing the bottleneck here? How can I tell whether vertical or horizontal scaling would be likely to help?

Answer (score 0):

There can be many bottlenecks. Let me list few:

- config limitation of application (for example you have maximum of 100 threads defined)
- context switching (between app and kernel)
- loaded only single core (you have 6 cores and load only one and total load is ~16%)
- disk bandwidth
- your test platform (where you run requests) reach limit of tests per second.
- your provider limit you